# Why do we use lifetime parameter when we create an account struct?

Tags: anchor, rust, account, lifetimes

This is an example of account struct in an anchor project.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info>{
    #[account(init,payer=user,space=264)]
    pub calculator:Account<'info,Calculator>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user:Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program:Program<'info,System>
}
```

As far as I know, generic lifetime parameters are only needed when we use references as output from a function. so why so we need a lifetime parameter for an account struct

Answer (score 2):

In a Solana program, accounts and their data are provided to a program, so the program can read / modify the data as it wants.  The Anchor `Account` type wraps the `solana_program::account_info::AccountInfo` type, which is itself a wrapper over Rust references.

Since `AccountInfo` holds references, those references must have lifetimes so that the Rust borrow checker can verify their usage.  By extension, Anchor `Account`s must also have lifetimes associated.

You can find more info about `AccountInfo` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/d351c58ff478bf4c9500fd1a2451b52307f668f6/sdk/program/src/account_info.rs#L18